# Get row position reference and fill down X number of times until you encounter a new value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In Google Sheets, I have a column that is randomly populated with a `value`:

```
1  value
2  
3  
4  value
5  value
6  
7  
8  
9  value
10
```

I need to populate all the blank, non-`value` cells in the column with a reference to the row number of the `value` above it.

Among many other things, I've tried using an IF statement:

`IF=A2="",row(A1),row(A2)`

This would look for a blank value in column A, give me a row reference if the value IS blank, and give me the value of the cell itself if it is not blank. However, this does not work when I fill down.

I am looking for a formula that will look at the values in column A and give me a row ref for the most recent appearance of `value` in that column:

```
1  value
2  1
3  1
4  value
5  value
6  5
7  5
8  5
9  value
10  9
```

Comment: what is your formula for "randomly printing value"?

Comment: No formula, I'm staging objects for ingest into a repository and each parent object has a variable number of children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", A1:A, 
 IF(ROW(A1:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A)), ROW(A1:A))),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), FILTER(ROW(A1:A), LEN(A1:A)), 1), )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks this works like a charm. still parsing how it actually works. i appreciate your fast help!